# Makefile compile error

Tags: c

I have an makefile but doesn't work. The error in terminal is this: **cc -shared -o build/liblcthw.so src/lcthw/list.o**

**/usr/bin/ld: src/lcthw/list.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
src/lcthw/list.o: error adding symbols: Bad value**

I need help to put the gcc comand gcc -shared -o target.so -fPIC target.c, i don't how to put the target.c instead list.o
This is the makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/liblcthw.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
    VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
BADFUNCS='[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)|stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)'
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep $(BADFUNCS) $(SOURCES) || true
```

Comment: Install [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (a debugging clone of GNU `make`) and run `remake -x`, or with a recent GNU make run `make --trace` to debug your issue. Look also at the output of `make -p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects for `liblcthw.a` are built with `-fPIC`. Objects for `liblcthw.so` are not built with this setting.

Try changing rule:

```
$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
```

to:

```
$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^
```

Since the required objects are already in `liblcthw.a`.

Or, alternatively:

```
$(SO_TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(SO_TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
```